# What happens when an Animate Dead reanimates a dormant god?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Under the Gatherer rulings for [Animate Dead](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAnimate%20Dead%5d), one point reads (emphasis mine):

> If the creature put onto the battlefield has protection from black—or if the creature can’t legally be enchanted by Animate Dead for another reason—Animate Dead won’t be able to attach to it. It will be put into the graveyard as a state-based action, causing its delayed triggered ability to trigger. When the trigger resolves, if the **creature’s** still on the battlefield, its controller will sacrifice it.

If I use an Animate Dead to reanimate a [Karametra, God of Harvests](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKarametra%2c%20God%20of%20Harvests%5d) and don't have the appropriate devotion to make it a creature, what happens? The Gatherer ruling seems to imply that it would be sacrificed because the Animate Dead can't be attached to it, but it's also specific in that you sacrifice the **creature**, which Karametra wouldn't be.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you do still sacrifice Karametra. Magic cards frequently use words like "the creature" to refer to a previously defined object, but it doesn't actually have to meet the criteria of those words. [CR 608.2i](http://blogs.magicjudges.org/rules/cr608/#2i) spells this out explicitly:

> If an ability’s effect refers to a specific untargeted object that has been previously referred to by that ability’s cost or trigger condition, it still affects that object even if the object has changed characteristics.
>   *Example: Wall of Tears says “Whenever Wall of Tears blocks a creature, return that creature to its owner’s hand at end of combat.” If Wall of Tears blocks a creature, then that creature ceases to be a creature before the triggered ability resolves, the permanent will still be returned to its owner’s hand.*

Comment: Does it matter that this is in Gatherer rulings instead of printed on Animate Dead? It would seem to me that the Gatherer ruling would be more specific in its wording.

Comment: @SocioMatt Generally Gatherer rulings don't deal with corner cases (unless the ruling is about that corner case). Also Gatherer rulings aren't actually rules, they just clarify how rules work in some circumstances, the actual rules always trump Gatherer rulings.